# Cannot install Kubernetes Metrics Server

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to install Kubernetes Metrics Server and try the Metrics API by following [this recipe](https://github.com/feiskyer/kubernetes-handbook/blob/73da37056c9c6a421be25c7b3ac42a481794ab9c/en/addons/metrics.md) (from Kubernetes Handbook). I currently have a Kubernetes 1.13 cluster that was installed with kubeadm.

The recipe's section [Enable API Aggregation](https://github.com/feiskyer/kubernetes-handbook/blob/73da37056c9c6a421be25c7b3ac42a481794ab9c/en/addons/metrics.md#enable-api-aggregation) recommends changes several settings in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-apiserver.yaml`. The current settings are as follows:

```
--proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.crt
--proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-client.key
--requestheader-allowed-names=front-proxy-client
--requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/front-proxy-ca.crt
--requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
--requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
--requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
```

The suggested new settings are as follows:

```
--requestheader-client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/proxy-ca.crt
--proxy-client-cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/proxy.crt
--proxy-client-key-file=/etc/kubernetes/certs/proxy.key
--requestheader-allowed-names=aggregator
--requestheader-extra-headers-prefix=X-Remote-Extra-
--requestheader-group-headers=X-Remote-Group
--requestheader-username-headers=X-Remote-User
```

If I install metrics-server without these changes its log contains errors like this:

> unable to fully collect metrics: ... unable to fetch metrics from
>   Kubelet ... x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Where do these credentials come from and what do they entail? I currently do not have a directory `/etc/kubernetes/certs`.

**UPDATE** I've now tried adding the following at suitable places inside `metrics-server-deployment.yaml`, however the issue still persists (in the absence of `--kubelet-insecure-tls`):

```
command:
- /metrics-server
- --client-ca-file
- /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt

volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
  name: ca
  readOnly: true

volumens:
- hostPath:
    path: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
    type: File
  name: ca
```

**UPDATE** [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/issues/146#issuecomment-472797066) is probably the reason why mounting the CA certificate into the container apparently did not help.

Answer (score 2):

### About Kubernetes Certificates:

Take a look on to how to [Manage TLS Certificates in a Cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/certificates/):

> Every Kubernetes cluster has a cluster root Certificate Authority
>   (CA). The CA is generally used by cluster components to validate the
>   API server’s certificate, by the API server to validate kubelet client
>   certificates, etc. To support this, the CA certificate bundle is
>   distributed to every node in the cluster and is distributed as a
>   secret attached to default service accounts.

And also [PKI Certificates and Requirements](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/certificates/):

> Kubernetes requires PKI certificates for authentication over TLS. If
>   you install Kubernetes with `kubeadm`, the certificates that your
>   cluster requires are automatically generated.

`kubeadm`, by default, create the Kubernetes certificates at **`/etc/kubernetes/pki/`** directory.

### About the metrics-server error:

It looks like the metrics-server is trying to validate the kubelet serving certs without having them be signed by the main Kubernetes CA. Installation tools like `kubeadm` may don't set up certificates properly.

This problem can also happen in the case of your server have changed names/addresses after the Kubernetes installation, which causes a mismatch of the `apiserver.crt` `Subject Alternative Name` and your current names/addresses. Check it with:

```
openssl x509 -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt -text -noout | grep DNS
```

The fastest/easy way to overcome this error is by using the **`--kubelet-insecure-tls`** flag for metrics-server. Something like this:

```
# metrics-server-deployment.yaml
[...]
- name: metrics-server
        image: k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.1
        command:
        - /metrics-server
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls
```

**Note that this implies security concerns**. If you are running for tests, ok. But for production, the best approach is to identify and fix the certificate issues (Take a look at this metrics-server issue for more information: [#146](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/issues/146))

Comment: Yes, `--kubelet-insecure-tls` ("Do not verify CA of serving certificates presented by Kubelets.") overcomes the issue. Thank you very much. I still don't see how to fix it for production, though. The kubelet's cert appears to be signed by the Kubernetes CA alright (`openssl verify -CAfile /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem`), so what to do?

Comment: Please see also my Update to the question.

Comment: Did you try to set the [`serverTLSBootstrap: true`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet-tls-bootstrapping/) in your kubelet's config? Take a look at [this](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/issues/146#issuecomment-472655656) comment and the related ones.

Comment: Can you advise on how this option can be added on an existing cluster in a "clean" way? Overwriting files previously generated by `kubeadm` (e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`) does not seem right.

Comment: @rookie099 Sorry, I cannot advise you...I know the existence of [`kubeadm config`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-config/) and [`kubeadm upgrade`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/) commands, but I never needed to update an existing cluster using `kubeadm`. Try asking another question about how to accomplish this, maybe someone can help you more than me. Good luck, and let me know your solution!

Comment: Again, thanks for your help. I'll post another question as you say.

Comment: Hi @rookie099. Did you manage it to work? If so, which approach did you use for upgrade the cluster config with `kubeadm`?

Comment: No, I've turned to other things in the meantime and will return to this at a later time.

Comment: @rookie099 I can answer your question in your first comment. Pass the `--kubelet-certificate-authority` flag to your metrics server with the location of your cluster's CA cert. If your kubelet client cert has been generated with the proper x509 extensions and the proper Subject name, then it will work.